# Huge Whitespace exists to right after drawing image. Want to get rid of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics, gdi+, barcode

I'm using the following codeproject to build an asp.net website and so far everything is good. My only problem is after the barcode is generated, a huge whitespace exist to the right of the barcode. I've been playing with this and am unable to resolve it.

Details below:

Link to Code Project Article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspBarCodes.aspx?msg=3543809

Copy of the Font is here: http://trussvillemethodist.web01.appliedi-labs.net/IDAutomationHC39M.ttf

```
          //Working Path
        string sWorkPath = "";
        sWorkPath = this.Context.Server.MapPath("");

        //Fonts
        PrivateFontCollection fnts = new PrivateFontCollection();
        fnts.AddFontFile(sWorkPath + @"\IDAutomationHC39M.ttf");
        FontFamily fntfam = new FontFamily("IDAutomationHC39M", fnts);
        Font oFont = new Font(fntfam, 18);

        // Get the Requested code sent from the previous page.
        string strCode = Request["code"].ToString();

        //Graphics
        //I don't know what to set the width to as I can't call the MeasureString without creating the Graphics object.
        Bitmap oBitmaptemp = new Bitmap(40, 100);
        Graphics oGraphicstemp = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmaptemp);
        int w = (int)oGraphicstemp.MeasureString(strCode, oFont).Width + 4;

        // Create a bitmap object of the width that we calculated and height of 100
        Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(w, 100);

        // then create a Graphic object for the bitmap we just created.
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);

        // Let's create the Point and Brushes for the barcode
        PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
        SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        // Now lets create the actual barcode image
        // with a rectangle filled with white color
        oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);

        // We have to put prefix and sufix of an asterisk (*),
        // in order to be a valid barcode
        oGraphics.DrawString("*" + strCode + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);

        // Then we send the Graphics with the actual barcode
        Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        oBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

        oBitmap.Dispose();
        oGraphics.Dispose();
        oBrush.Dispose();
        oFont.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 3):

The code just assumes 40 pixels per character, which is why you get a lot of image left on the right of the text. You can use the `MeasureString` method to measure the size of the text, and use that to create an image of the correct size:

```
int w = (int)oGraphics.MeasureString("*123$10.00*", oFont).Width + 4;
```

I noticed that you don't dispose any of the objects that you are using. The `Graphics`, `Bitmap`, `SolidBrush` and `Font` objects need to be disposed.

You might also want to consider using a GIF image instead of JPEG, it's more suited for this kind of graphics.

Comment: Sorry, can you spell this out for me. I can't call the oGraphics or oFont because it hasn't been instantiated yet. I also move the "int w" down because its used to create the Bitmap object. The "Code" string is coming from a something.aspx?code=123$2.00

Comment: Your code is also implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.SizeF' to 'int' which is not allowed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @mbcrump: The overload used only has two parameters, the `4` is added afterwards, it's not a third parameter.

Comment: Graphics.MeasureString returns a SizeF type. It will not compile with the way that you specified. If you can write some sample code for me with this working then it would be much appreciated. I am spinning my wheels on this.

Comment: @mbcrump: Oh, now I see what you mean. It returns both the width and height of the text, so you need to use the `Width` property to get the desired value. As that it a `float` you have to cast it to `int`.

Comment: Why are you adding +4, shouldn't that be 40?

Comment: @mbcrump: Because you draw the text at 2,2, so I assumed that you wanted a 2 pixel margin on the right also.

Comment: I've updated my code above with some of your initial suggestions, I still can't seem to get the barcode to generate correctly. I've added a few comments. Thanks

Comment: Let me also add that I can adjust the 4 to 40 and the image looks ok, but it will no longer scan.

Comment: @mbcrump: You measure the string without the starting and trailing asterisk, so the width that you get is too small.